# How can I get the recipient’s Gmail iOS app to show my Google account’s avatar?

Tags: gmail

When I added my avatar to:

https://aboutme.google.com/u/2/

it started showing up on mail.google.com. When I signed up for Google+, it started showing up on inbox.google.com. But in the Gmail iOS app, it shows up as a solid-color circle with the first letter of my email address.

Comment: how long did you wait? these things can take time to populate.

Comment: Solved! Inbox started working immediately, but gmail ios started working the next day.

Comment: Awesome! Submitted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many sites have a delay when loading new profile images. Be sure to give it at least 48 hours to populate.

Answer (score 0):

I just checked with my two accounts in Gmail on iOS. As a quick workaround: ask this person to add you to the Contact list and manually add the avatar in Google Contacts.